# What are some techniques for "balancing" a tree beside heavy-light and centroid decomposition?

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, tree, dynamic-algorithms

The only techniques i know are those in the title.

Comment: Balancing may not be the correct term, balancing refers to AVL, Red Black, Splay tree like structures. You seem to be looking at decomposition. What kind of decomposition are u interested in. Look for Topology Trees, Top Trees, Euler Tour Trees, Sleator Tarjan Trees (uses heavy light decomposition) for several similar decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper "Algorithmic Meta Theorems for Circuit Classes of Constant and Logarithmic Depth" (Elberfeld, Jacobi, Tantau) gives a nice balanced tree decomposition based on tree contraction in $TC^0$:

https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2011/128/

Another nice $TC^0$-decomposition is based on so-called TSLPs in the paper "A Universal Tree Balancing Theorem" (Ganardi, Lohrey):

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08705.pdf